# Call Fragments onCreateView in context with Tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments

I have 2 Tabs and 2 Corresponding Fragments. On calling the LAUNCH Activity both Tabs were added and then the first one added will be shown. Thus the first Fragments onCreateView is called the second Fragments ones not.
In my case this is an issue because the first Fragment has to call methods on the second Fragment. Inside the second Fragment there is an Objectreference which will be set by calling the onCreateView in the second Fragment.
Therefore I used following code snippet to solve this

```
actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(1);
actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(0);
```

It works but in my opinion there must be another possibility to solve this issue. Like calling the onCreateView of the second Fragment?

Here is the relevant code snippet. The listener is implemented as in android-dev Sample only with small changes not affecting my issue.

simplexFragment corresponds to the first Fragment

graphicFragment corresponds to the second Fragment

```
// adds two tabs
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Input").setTabListener(new TabListener(null,  "input_fragment")));

graphicFragment = new GraphicFragment();

actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Graphic").setTabListener(new TabListener(graphicFragment, "graphic_fragment")));
simplexFragment.setGraphics(graphicFragment); // sets the internal reference!

actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

// selects the Tab so the GraphicFragments onCreateView will be called
actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(1);
actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(0);
```

Thanks for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In my case this is an issue because the first Fragment has to call methods on the second Fragment.

This is not how `Fragments` are meant to work. The idea is a `Fragment` should be self-contained and re-usable and one `Fragment` shouldn't know that another exists (or at least shouldn't rely the existence any other `Fragment`).

For example, suppose you have 3 `Fragments` and ActivityA uses FragmentA and FragmentB but you have another `Activity` (ActivityB) which uses FragmentA and FragmentC. In that case, FragmentA doesn't know what the other `Fragment` is (B or C) and shouldn't even expect there to be another `Fragment` at all.

The way to achieve what you want is to use callback methods on the `Activity` and have it perform the actions on any other `Fragments` (if they exist). It can do this by either calling public methods on the other `Fragments` or by passing data in the 'arguments' `Bundle` when it creates the other `Fragments`.

Comment: I have used Fragments because I want to build the UI for Tablet and Mobile-Phone. It's more of a historical grown issue - first I was working with callback methods but when implementing tabs there was a problem with the synchronization between the two Fragments (contained by each tab) and I had to make a reference from Fragment A-->B. 

OT: As a fan of patterns and interesting concepts like Fragments it really hurts that I have to use this concept in this way...